# javascript accessing array outside of function

Tags: arrays, variables, twitch

So I am making this twitch.tv api page for free code camp.
I am trying to iterate through the streamers array and push the data to the results array, sort by # of viewers and display the data from the results array on the page.

The problem is while the the .append stuff is in the for loop in writes the infor multiple times.  If I move it out of the for loop, the variables are undefined.

Any ideas out there from the smart people?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    getInfo();  
    var results = [];
    function getInfo(){
        var streamers = ["FreeCodeCamp","PlayHearthstone","summit1G","BradfordLee","Savjz","Z28RyanK"];
    streamers.forEach(function(streamers){
            $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels' + '/' + streamers + '?callback=?', function(data){

                var name = data.display_name;
                var game = data.game;
                var logo = data.logo;

                $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams' + '/' + streamers + '?callback=?', function(data){
                    var status = data.stream;
                    if(data.stream == undefined){
                        status = "Offline";
                    }else{
                        status = "Online";
                    }
                    var views = data.stream;
                    if(data.stream == undefined){
                        views = 0;
                    }else{
                        views = data.stream.viewers;
                    }
                    results.push({"name": name, "logo": logo, "status": status, "game": game, "views": views});
                    results.sort(function(b, a) {return parseFloat(a.views) -parseFloat(b.views);});
                    console.log(results);
                    results.forEach(function(results){
                        $('.main').append('<div><img src="' + logo + '"><p>' + name + '</p><p>' + status + '</p><p>' + game + '</p><p>' + views + '</p></div>');
                    })                      
    }   )               
})          
            })      
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why did you name your function parameter of the `forEach` callback the same as your array?  They're both called `streamers`.  Perhaps you're running into some scoping issues because of the name collision?

Comment: i thought i had to pass the streamers array there.  I don't know what i'm doing obviously  haha.

Comment: The `forEach` accepts a function, which you have defined inline.  That anonymous function defines its own parameter list.  `.forEach` expects that function to accept parameters that represent the `element, index, entireArray` as from the parent array.  See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example#Parameters).  Try changing your function parameter to something like `streamer` (no `s`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move out the append line. You say you don't have access to the variables, but you just stored them in the `results` array, so you can access them from there. So simply move out the line and change is as such:

```
results.forEach(function(result){
    $('.main').append('<div><img src="' + result.logo + '"><p>' + result.name + '</p><p>' + result.status + '</p><p>' + result.game + '</p><p>' + result.views + '</p></div>');
})
```

(Do note that you shouldn't do `results.forEach(function(results){` using the name `results` twice, similar with `streamers`. You're running a `forEach` over `results`, so it's for each `result` (not plural))

Below I have rewritten your piece of code, fixing some errors. See it in action in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t56hdeq/4/).

```
var streamers;
var streamCallsCompleted;
var results;

$(document).ready(function() {
    streamers = ["FreeCodeCamp", "PlayHearthstone", "summit1G", "BradfordLee", "Savjz", "Z28RyanK"];
    results = [];
    streamCallsCompleted = 0;

    getAndAppendInfo(streamers);

    // parseFloat shouldn't be necessary as views should be a whole number
    results.sort(function(b, a) {
        return parseInt(a.views) - parseInt(b.views);
    });


});

function getAndAppendInfo(streamers) {
    streamers.forEach(
        function(streamer) {
            $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels' + '/' + streamer + '?callback=?', function(data) {
            channelCallSuccess(data, streamer)
            })
                .fail(channelCallError);
        });
}

function channelCallError() {
    streamCallsCompleted++;

    checkAndAppendResults();
}

function streamCallError() {
    streamCallsCompleted++;

    checkAndAppendResults();
}

function channelCallSuccess(data, streamer) {


    var name = data.display_name;
    var game = data.game;
    var logo = data.logo;

    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams' + '/' + streamer + '?callback=?', function(data) {
        streamCallsCompleted++;

        var status = data.stream ? "Online" : "Offline";
        var views = data.stream ? data.stream.viewers : 0;

        results.push({
            "name": name,
            "logo": logo,
            "status": status,
            "game": game,
            "views": views
        });

        checkAndAppendResults();
    });
}

function checkAndAppendResults() {
    if (streamCallsCompleted < streamers.length) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(results);
    results.forEach(function(result) {
        $('.main').append('<div><img src="' + result.logo + '"><p>' + result.name + '</p><p>' + result.status + '</p><p>' + result.game + '</p><p>' + result.views + '</p></div>');
    });
}
```

Basically, the gist here is that the getJSON call is asynchronous. This means that this piece of code is not executed in order. As such we have to keep track of how many calls we make. Only when all calls have either succeeded or erred, we will process the results.

Comment: So when I move it outside the array is just "[]"  and nothing is displayed.

Comment: This still just returns an empty array.

Comment: Ah my bad, I just rewrote your code and didn't notice `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function. (Which means it's not executed nicely in order but only executes once it's done) Give me a moment to rewrite.

Comment: Nice!  that works.  Only I still need the other .getJSON 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams' to get the status and views variables as they are not in the channels call.

Comment: Added that call too as well as check if the call fails so it will still compute all. Note how that call is nested so it will only execute once it's actually found the channel. It's also possible to do the two calls separately, but then you'll have to merge the results which is more difficult.

Comment: okay but I'm not sure if the second call is working.  i get bad request 400 errors when i try to console log the data from it.

Comment: Check my most recent edit (apparently it didn't submit)

Comment: Sweet !  You got it.  Thanks for the help.